# Difference between prefixes "об" and "по"

Tags: грамматика

What is the difference between prefixes об and по. For example облизать and полизать.

Comment: [о-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE-), [по-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE-)

Answer (score 2):

Roughly said, ***об-*** means '[centered] around' and ***по-*** means 'along [and then to somewhere else]'. The difference is also in cases for adverbial complement - not  always but quite often, e. g.

***Дети облазили чердак.*** = The kids have investigated all the loft through.

***Я обдумаю это.*** = I'll think about this.

***Она обделала порог.*** = She shat around [all] the threshold.

***Дети полазали на чердаке.*** = The kids has been investigating the loft [for a while].

***Я подумаю об этом.*** = I'll think about this [and then I'll shift to some other topic].

***Он поделал порог.*** = He's been making a threshold [for a while and then he switched to some other activity].

Sometimes the difference is that ***об-*** refers to a non-literal meaning, while ***по-***  indicates the action as it is, thus making the meaning entirely different, e. g.

***Я обрёл смысл.*** = I've found [the supreme] meaning [of/in smth]. NB: the ***об-*** is regarded by some researchers as a part of the stem, but the stem actually is a historical cognate of Lithuanian *ràsti* and  *surė̃sti* (acc. to Fasmer).

***Я побрёл своим путём.*** = I wended my way along.

***Дым обволок кострище.*** = The smoke coated the fireplace.

***Волк поволок ягнёнка в тёмный лес.*** = A wolf was taking a lamb into a dark forest.

***Дела обстоят хорошо.*** = The things / the circumstances are OK.

***Они постоят и пойдут.*** = They'll stand there for a while and then they'll part.

Hence, the difference between ***облизать*** and ***полизать*** will be as follows:

***Котёнок облизал сметану.*** = The kitten has licked [all the] sour creme [around].

***Котёнок полизал сметану.*** = The kitten has licked some sour creme [for a while and then switched to some other activity].

Comment: В слове "обрести" приставки нет.

Comment: Не установлено.

Comment: В таком случае можно дать однокоренные слова? Дайте хоть одно.

Comment: Pls see the post above after the mark NB regarding the Lithuanian cognates.